# Django auth without "auth_*" tables

Tags: python, django, authentication

We would like to use our own tables for user management instead of the Django "auth" tables. We already have database tables that include all of the relevant information our application needs but it isn't in the Django format. We would prefer not to have the information duplicated in two tables.

We would like to utilize the auth package, though, as there is some very nice functionality that we don't want to replicate.

I realize we could build our own [auth backend](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-backends), but that doesn't, as far as I can tell, remove the need for two sets of tables in this case.

Am I correct in assuming that we *cannot* do this? I have found no docs that discuss how to modify the underlying model that the auth package is using. The backend simply pre-populates the user object that would eventually be saved in the auth tables.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what functionality from the auth module that you want to keep?

Comment: Pretty much all of it. :) With any objects I create, I can coax my model objects into using my existing tables by specifying specific columns and tables in the ORM code. That's what I would like to be able to do with the auth package, but I'd rather not modify the underlying django code if I can help it.

Right now, we are going to bite the bullet and have the user data in two tables, synced at login using a custom backend and synced at save using a save notification. My question was basically, "Am I right that there isn't a better way to do this currently?"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).  That integrates nicely with the rest of django.contrib.auth and allows you to write it against a legacy user table.  You need to do this with care and migrate data properly (all of which is described in the documentation).